# ember: modeling a shopping cart in ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm struggling with getting my head around modeling a shopping cart that needs to persist to the back-end.  I think I understand the relationships, and how to retrieve data that's *in* the model...it's how to actually add the data that's tripping me up.

I've got two pretty simple models:

The cart:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    cartitems: hasMany('cartitem')
});
```

The cart items

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    product: belongsTo('product', { async: true }),
    cart: belongsTo('cart'),

    variantCodes: attr(''),
    quantity: attr('number'),
    itemPrice: attr('number'),
    itemOrigPrice: attr('number')

});
```

I created a cart service that contains properties, computed properties and methods.  In this cart service is where I'm having the trouble, starting with my `add` method:

```
...

add(item) {
    this.get('store').findRecord('cart', get(this, 'cartId')).then(result => {
        cart.get('cartitems').addObject(this.get('store').createRecord('cartitem', {
                id: item.skuid,
                variantCodes: item.variantCodes,
                quantity: item.quantity,
                itemPrice: item.itemPrice
            })
        );
        cart.save();
    });
}
```

That kind of works...it shows the `cart` and `cartitem` models (with data and relationsips) in the ember inspector, but doesn't send a payload for the cart items to the API.  I'm thinking it's because I have to do a `save` for each `cartitem`.

But this rig also seems overly complex and I think would result in a bunch of network requests.  Is this even the right approach?

I *think* the DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin would help here, but I have no idea how that would look.  I can't seem to find any examples of it in use for POSTing to the API.  Only for retrieving.  Any help appreciated!

Comment: This is an excellent question actually. Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled on something that seems to work.  This uses the ember-concurrency task syntax but that is not a requirement.

```
addItem: task(function * (product, quantity) {

    let cart = this.get('store').findRecord('cart').get('firstObject'); // or whatever is aliased to the cart record

    // check if the item is already in cart
    let cartItem = yield this.get('store').peekAll('cart-item').findBy('skuid', skuid);
    if (cartItem) {
        cartItem.setProperties({
            skuid: product.get('skuid'),
            cart: cart,
            product: product,
            quantity: cartItem.get('quantity') + quantity
        });
    } else {
        cartItem = yield this.get('store').createRecord('cart-item', {
            skuid: product.get('skuid'),
            cart: cart,
            product: product,
            quantity: quantity
        });
    }

    // persist to back end
    let savedItem = null
    try {
        savedItem = yield cartItem.save();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("failed out of cartitem save", e);
    }

    // if adding an item can affect the cart (dynamic pricing, promo thresholds)
    // you can do a save of the entire cart here to get it updated
    yield cart.save();

    return savedItem;

});
```